# Does AWSLambdaFullAccess policy not include lambda invoke function permission?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I'm trying to invoke lambda function.

The account I'm using contains 'AWSLambdaFullAccess' and 'AWSLambdaRole' policy which contains all permission related to Lambda.
When testing the lambda function, getting this error message :

```
    {"errorMessage":"User: arn:aws:sts::186XXXXXX:assumed-role/lambda_basic_execution/gettestplans is not authorized to perform: lambda:InvokeFunction on resource: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:1866XXXXXX:function:verifytoken","errorType":"AccessDeniedException"
```

Here is the code :

```
  lambda.invoke({
      FunctionName: 'verifytoken',
      Qualifier: process.env.ENVIRONMENT,
      InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
      Payload: '{"authorizationToken": "'+event.Authorization+'"}'
  }, function(error, data) {
  if (error) {
    callback(error,null);
  }
  if(data.Payload){
    data=JSON.parse(data.Payload);
    if(typeof data.errorMessage == "string" && data.errorMessage == "Unauthorized"){
      callback(null,data);
    }else{
    console.log("This is working")
  }
 }
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: *"The account I'm using contains..."*  You're not using an account, here.  This isn't an account being unable to invoke the function, it appears to be this execution role `lambda_basic_execution/gettestplans` that isn't able to invoke another function.  The code you've shown appears to be from one lambda function that is trying to invoke another, but it isn't really clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the role permissions attached to the lambda functions.
I have changed the permissions of the role and now I'm able to execute the same function successfully.